# Unable to get public events using Facebook Graph API for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am able to login, get the user profile data, and even pull photos from a public page's photo library.  The issue is when I try to access the page's events list using:

```
graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/events
```

all that is returned is a blank array.

On `http://www.facebook.com/BeerLovesSouthside/events` you can see a full list of events.  Even using the graph explorer tool I am not getting any errors about access tokens or anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> On http://www.facebook.com/BeerLovesSouthside/events you can see a full list of events.

That’s events *created* by that page.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#connections says,

> events: The events the Page is **attending**.

So I guess if you want the events *created* by the page, you have to read the corresponding posts from their feed by type.

Comment: That pointed me in the right direction.  It ended up being under links.  Then just had to search through and find "/events/EVENT_ID" in the link field.  Thank you.